# Using a pointer variable typedef

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

I define a typedef

```
typedef char* charP;
```

Then I declare a few variables

```
charP dog, cat, fish;
```

Are all the variables of type `char*` or is `dog` the only `char*` while `cat` and `fish` are of type `char`?

Comment: All of them are `char *`

Comment: `printf("%d %d %d\n", sizeof dog, sizeof cat, sizeof fish);` would have given you the answer in an instant.

Comment: @glglgl The proper formatting code for values of type `size_t` is `%zu`.

Comment: @unwind While you are completely right, for a quick test it should work as well. But there is a chance that I run into trouble with that, so better do it right your way. But then I'd have to lookup the `z`, and I hadn't the answer in an instant, but in several minutes :-}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All of them are of type `charP`, which is an alias for `char *`, so yes, they're all pointers.

That said, some people (me included) consider it a bad idea to "hide" the pointer asterisk, since it breaks the symmetry between declaring the variable and accessing it.

You're going to have:

```
charP a;

*a = '1';  /* What?! It didn't look like a pointer, above?! */
```

... which causes confusion. Generally, pointers in C are important to keep track of, so hiding what is a pointer and what isn't can lead to trouble.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, I don't quite ... agree that those were ever a good idea. :)

Comment: Well, MS loves the Macros and typedefs, some of them even make sense because they hint at semantics (like `BSTR`). Would be nice if they changed to standard types where possible someday, though...

Answer (score 1):

All of them are `char *`. Do not confuse it with this case: `char *dog, cat, fish;`. Here, `dog` is a `char *`, and rest are just `char`s.

Answer (score 0):

All of them are char pointers as you are using typedef and not macro.

so it will not behave like char *dog, cat, fish;